# How to split a 6 digit number into one column with 4 digits and one column with 2 digits (for example: 201452 into 2014 and 52)

Tags: pyspark

How to split a 6 digit number into one column with 4 digits and one column with 2 digits (for example: 201452 into 2014 and 52) in PySpark. It should systematically split the 6 digit numbers after the fourth digit.

I already tried the `pyspark.split(...)` method but there I am not able to split the 6 digit numbers based on the position. How can I specify this position?

```
split_col=py.sql.functions.split(lambda x: df_datetime["WEEKNR"], '4')
df_datetime=df_datetime.withColumn('Name 1', split_col.getItem(0)).show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just looking for the function [`substring`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.substring)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
    "four_let",
    F.substring(F.col("WEEKNR"), 1, 4)
)
```